# SPECTROCHEMPY txt file won't upload

Tags: python, file

I have a file that for some reason in python using the spectrochempy package, results in a NoneType object. Other files have worked, this is the only one I've been having trouble with. The error says that I can't convert float NaN to integer. But other files with what I presume to be "NaN" values (they're the same format) work totally fine.

I tried to open the data set using this code:

```
import spectrochempy as scp 
dataset = scp.read("path to file")
```

and using this

```
import spectrochempy as scp 
dataset = scp.read_labspec("path to file")
```

Both had the same errors. I want to use the scp package because it is raman spectra data and I want to work it up using this package. Thanks! I can open the file fine in matlab